# Directive with multiple ngmodel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

I have a custom directive that requires an ngModel such as:

```
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        counter: '@',
        modelResult: '=ngModel'
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    controller: controller,
```

When I call my directive multiple times with different models assigned to it they don't get updated after changing them inside the directive however, when I just have one call to my directive it does update.

Multiple calls: (ngModel doesn't update for each)

```
<div class="fg-line" ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3,4,5]">
  <combobox obj-send-back="AcctString" 
            flag-type="" 
            max-acct-shown="10" 
            max-seg-shown="5"
            counter="{{$index}}"
            ng-model="item.AcctString"></combobox>
</div>
```

Single Call: (ngModel does update)

```
<combobox obj-send-back="AcctString" 
            flag-type="" 
            max-acct-shown="10" 
            max-seg-shown="5"
            counter="{{$index}}"
            ng-model="item.AcctString"></combobox>
```

The goal is to have each ngModel updated from the directive.

Additional info: I am using watches to listen for changes too
Example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sz68p7et/4/)

Comment: please create a minimal verifiable example that replicates the issue. people will be able to help you better

Comment: It's not really clear what your issue is.  Your example doesn't really make sense, because even though you have an `ng-repeat`, that `ng-repeat` has nothing to do with the object you are trying to pass through `ng-model`.

Comment: also, in your fiddle, you are using primitives, which don't play well with `ng-repeat`.  `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each instance, so trying to watch properties from `$scope` in the parent controller won't work.  besides that, you would have 5 (in this case) different copies of the property, but you are only watching one possible copy.  What you are trying to do just plain doesn't make sense.

Comment: ok, but if in your controller you have `$scope.newAcctString`, then you pass it through an `ng-repeat`, you have 5 possible `newAcctString` values, but only one `newAcctString` variable.  That's why your `ng-repeat` has to be based on something related to your data, not just an arbitrary array.

Comment: I am new with directives and don't understand them very well.
I am trying to pass a variable to the directive and do something inside of it. Once it gets updated I want to return that to the parent controller.
I want to be able to do this for multiple variables inside an ngrepeat.

If the ngrepeat creates a child scope for every instance then I think that is my problem.

Comment: again, I don't think this is a problem with your directive. This seems more like a problem with the scenario you are describing itself.  **why are you using an ng-repeat**?  What is the purpose of showing 5 different copies of the same input box?  If you can describe how you are using these different copies through the `ng-repeat`, it might make more sense how to get the value you want passed in and out.

Comment: I have updated my code example.
I need to have it inside an ngrepeat because I am basically trying to update the account of each available account . The directive does some parsing to the accounts and then it is supposed to return that and update the model of whatever input was called .
If user updates obj[2].acct  I want to get the new variable after it is updated from the directive.
Hopefully it makes more sense, my only goal is to be able to pass a variable to my directive, do some custom stuff and return it so that the parent controller can save it in a database.

Comment: I figure it out, the problem was that I was using "var" inside my directive and because of this I didn't have an isolated variable which was messing my directive up. Thanks for the answers even if my question didn't make much sense at first